# Do you need to download webkit?

Tags: css, webkit

I am following an tutorial that is typing -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; in the style.css nothing seems to happen when I write it... I am on windows and using atom. is it something you need to download? I understand an engine and something to do with animation in chrome/safari.

Comment: You don't need to download anything to use webkit.  Could you post your code?

Comment: *-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;* --> this property no more exist. You have to simply use `box-sizing: border-box;` and you should stop reading very very old tutorial (check the date when you find them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to download anythig. `webkit` is one of the prefixes used to make experimental css properties work for other browsers, they are temporary and you should remove them from your code once a property is fully supported by all browsers.

**This is a list of prefixes used:**

- **-webkit-** (Chrome, Safari, iOS Safari / iOS WebView, Android)
- **-moz-** (Firefox)
- **-ms-** (Edge, Internet Explorer)
- **-o-** (Opera, Opera Mini)

to determine if a property need vendor prefixes or not, use **[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/)** they mention on the notes if the property searched is experimental.

once you found that you need to use prefixes, here is an easy tool to auto-prefix
**[AutoPrefixes](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)**

the following are some articles for more in depth reading:

- https://flaviocopes.com/css-vendor-prefixes/
- https://www.lifewire.com/css-vendor-prefixes-3466867
- https://bitsofco.de/css-vendor-prefixes/